# Compare a generic object to an integer

Tags: java, generics

While working on my project, I made a function to select a random object from an `ArrayList`. Each object has a variable min and max which defines the percentage the object has of being chosen.

The function works perfectly, but I use a dozen slight variations of it since I have a lot of `ArrayList`s with different types of objects, which I need to use it on. Therefore, I want to make it generic so I'd only have one variant of the function, which I can use for all my lists. At the moment, I have this:

```
public static <G> int selRan(ArrayList<G> list){
        int sel = 0;
        Random rand = new Random();
        int  randNum = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            if(list.get(i).min <= randNum && randNum < list.get(i).max){
                sel = i;
            }
        }
        return sel;
}
```

This is where I ran into a snag, as `list.get(i).min` and `list.get(i).max` don't work. I have no clue on how to approach this.

Comment: I am not incredibly familiar with generics, but I believe you will still need to determine the type of the objects within the `ArrayList` at some point and process them differently. So a `switch` or `if`` tree is needed to check what type is being worked on.

Comment: You either check the type and case, or make it a list of things implementing a min/max interface. Personally I'd prefer the latter.

Comment: Your generic type G should  extend SomeSuperClassOrInterfaceWithMinAndMax.

Comment: If not able/willing to implement an interface as others mentioned, you could do a simple `if (list.get(0) instanceof ClassType)`

Comment: @Zephyr (Which was also mentioned :)

Comment: @DaveNewton - yes, by both of us :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your type parameter `G` has no bound, so the compiler can't assume that any methods are available except for `Object` methods.

If you expect `max` and `main` to be available on different, unrelated objects that are in your lists, then create an interface that declares this functionality.

```
interface MinMax {
    int getMin();
    int getMax();
}
```

Have all your different, unrelated objects implements this interface.  Then declare `G` with an upper bound of `MinMax` (or whatever you decide to call it), so that these methods will be guaranteed to be available to be called.

```
// Declare upper bound here.
public static <G extends MinMax> int selRan(ArrayList<G> list){
    int sel = 0;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int  randNum = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        // Call interface methods here.
        if(list.get(i).getMin() <= randNum && randNum < list.get(i).getMax()){
            sel = i;
        }
    }
    return sel;
}
```

You may also decide to program to the interface and accept a `List<G>` instead of an `ArrayList<G>` for flexibility.

You may find that you can just use a wildcard with the bound, because the exact type of `G` doesn't matter.

```
public static int selRan(List<? extends MinMax> list){
    int sel = 0;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int  randNum = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        // Call interface methods here.
        if(list.get(i).getMin() <= randNum && randNum < list.get(i).getMax()){
            sel = i;
        }
    }
    return sel;
}
```